# WordPress Side Navigation with Parent Heading and Child Sub Pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following navigational structure in WordPress:

```
  Page
     Sub Page
        Child Page
        Child Page
        Child Page
  Page
     Sub Page
        Child Page
        Child Page
        Child Page
  Page
     Sub Page
        Child Page
        Child Page
        Child Page
```

On each Sub Page and Child Page, I want to display the following in the sidebar:

```
  Sub Page
        Child Page
        Child Page
        Child Page
```

The closest I've come to this is the following code from [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/list-only-page-siblings?replies=19):

```
<ul>
<?php
global $post;
$current_page_parent = ( $post->post_parent ? $post->post_parent : $post->ID );      
wp_list_pages( array(
       'title_li' => '',
       'child_of' => $current_page_parent,
       'depth' => '1' )
);
?>
</ul>
```

However, on Sub Pages it only shows a list of all Sub Pages (without Child Pages) and on Child Pages, it displays a list of Child Pages of that section but the parent Sub Page title is missing.

How do I modify to achieve what I'm looking for?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right this is not showing parent page on child or sub for that you may use following code.

```
<?php if ( $post->post_parent ) {
$children = wp_list_pages( array(
    'title_li' => '',
    'child_of' => $post->post_parent,
    'echo'     => 0
) );
$title = get_the_title( $post->post_parent ); } else {
$children = wp_list_pages( array(
    'title_li' => '',
    'child_of' => $post->ID,
    'echo'     => 0
) );
$title = get_the_title( $post->ID );} if ( $children ) : ?>
<h2><?php echo $title; ?></h2>
<ul>
    <?php echo $children; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Looks good but I'm getting an error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in eval()'d code on line 17

Comment: Friend, that should not be error of my code, i have tested working fine , also if you read the error they are saying about $end which not used in my code, so please review your code. if till getting error than tell me in more deep.

Comment: Sorry, I've tested this a few times and still getting the same error. Also, if I paste the code into http://phptester.net, I get the following error: `FATAL ERROR syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting elseif (T_ELSEIF) or else (T_ELSE) or endif (T_ENDIF) on line number 14`

Answer (score 0):

Mukesh Ram's code is working, just missing the final ENDIF

```
<?php if ( $post->post_parent ) {
    $children = wp_list_pages( array(
        'title_li' => '',
        'child_of' => $post->post_parent,
        'echo'     => 0
    ) );
    $title = get_the_title( $post->post_parent ); } else {
    $children = wp_list_pages( array(
        'title_li' => '',
        'child_of' => $post->ID,
        'echo'     => 0
    ) );
    $title = get_the_title( $post->ID );} if ( $children ) : ?>
    <h2><?php echo $title; ?></h2>
    <ul>
        <?php echo $children; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
```